# Create a 301 redirect for Con.htm

Tags: asp.net, html, iis-7

CON is a reserved word in the Windows file system.  I have a file linked in from many places Con.htm.  Unfortunately because of the file system naming restrictions I cannot actually upload a file with this name.  So I want to create a 301 permanent move from Con.htm to Con_.htm.  But I cannot create the file to perform a HTML redirect from.  So I tried urlMappings in my Web Config

```
<urlMappings enabled="true">
    <add url="~/0/Con.htm" mappedUrl="~/0/Con_.htm" />
</urlMappings>
```

But that isn't working.  So I installed the URL Rewrite Module for IIS 7.5.  I created a mapping entry:

Original value: /0/Con.htm
New value: /0/Con_.htm

This is not working form me as well.  I am not particular about the method to be used.  Can anyone suggest a different solution or correct what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Not the most practical, but you can do this in the global.asax.  Add an event handler to Application_BeginRequest, and do:

```
var url = Request.Url.ToString();
if (url.Contains("/con.html"))
   Response.RedirectPermanent("final URL");
```

See more info about [RedirectPermanent here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.redirectpermanent.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for the help.  Unfortunately, the BeginRequest does not fire on that filename Con.htm.  It fires for files present on the drive and non-existent files, just not on that file name.